# ASCII titles with Yoast SEO plugin

Tags: seo, title, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I'm finding that [SEOmoz](http://seomoz.org) is showing page titles with ASCII when indexing my customer's site http://bulldogfencespokane.com. I'm concerned that this is how search engines will index the site. I'd love to remove commas and apostrophes but it would change the sentence structure entirely. Is there a way to clear up this formatting?

```
Spokane &amp; Coeur d&#039;Alene&#039;s top fencing installers - Bulldog Fences Inc.
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:http://bulldogfencespokane.com/&hl=en), [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fbulldogfencespokane.com%2F&go=&form=QBLH&qs=n&sk=), [Yahoo](http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AmtIRjwQqAtCcGZn_2l_M8ObvZx4?p=bulldogfencespokane.com&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-701), etc.. to see if it's being indexed with the characters?

Comment: They haven't re-indexed since I made the changes. Last index was Mar 30th.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII characters will not cause any issues with search engines and they will be displayed properly. SEOmoz does this to avoid any chance of sql injection via its form fields.